# O que é e para que serve um monad?

Tags: programação-funcional

> Eu lembro que na universidade foi-me explicado o que é um `monad`, mas o tempo passou e eu já não sei mais o que ele é. Isto deve-se também ao pouco contacto que tenho com linguagens funcionais.

Em programação, o que é um *monad*? Qual é a sua utilidade?

Pode dar um exemplo duma utilização?

Comment: Uma resposta para isso vai ser bem extensa, é um conceito abstrato bem difícil de explicar. Esse link tem uma explicação bem divertida: http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html

Comment: Eu achei um bom exemplo aqui, se quiser eu traduzo, mas é em haskell.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad

Comment: @Marconi Obrigado já vi algumas respostas lá. Cabe a você decidir se faz uma tradução ou não. Uma coisa melhor que você pode fazer é resumir o conteúdo das várias respostas numa resposta sua.

Comment: @Marconi uma tradução ia cair bem...

Comment: O artigo [Tacking the Awkward Squad](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/marktoberdorf/mark.pdf) do Simon Peyton Jones é a melhor introdução para monadas que eu conheço. Explica bem o que é um monad é porque elas são tão necessárias para programação em Haskell. Em outras linguagens além de monadas não serem tão necessárias, é difícil abstrair sobre o convocê não precisa tanto de monadas e é difícil abstrair sobre o conceito de monadas sem "kigher kinded polymorphism", que é uma funcionalidade de sistema de tipos avançada.

Comment: Eu traduzi o post que mencionei acima. Como falei, acho que seria difícil explicar o que são Monads aqui (sem escrever um livro), então achei que colocar a resposta em outro lugar (Medium, ao meu ver mais fácil de criar um post - ainda mais um cheio de imagens) e compartilhá-la aqui faz sentido nesse contexto.

Functors, Applicatives e Monads explicados com desenhos: https://medium.com/@julianoalves/functors-applicatives-e-monads-explicados-com-desenhos-2c45d5db7d25#.l56dxh4k4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um Monad, resumidamente, é simplesmente um wrapper de um valor qualquer.

Exemplo:

```
function Maybe(value) {
  return {
    value: value
  }
}

const maybeString = Maybe('Novo Post No Blog')
maybeString.value // 'Novo Post No Blog'

const maybeNull = Maybe(null)
maybeNull.value // null
```

Comment: Maurício, uma dica. Selecionar o código e clicar **`Ctrl`** + **`K`** deixa ele formatado. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]